# Grails query cache is not used

Tags: hibernate, caching, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to cache the following query that is called from a controller:

```
def approvedCount = Book.countByApproved(true, [cache: true])
```

I have enabled the 2nd-level cache for the `Book` class, by adding

```
static mapping = {
    cache true
}
```

to `Book.groovy`. I also have the following configured in `DataSource.groovy`

```
hibernate {
  cache.use_second_level_cache = true
  cache.use_query_cache = true
  cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
```

In this same file I've enabled query logging by adding `logSql=true` in the `dataSource` block.

Every time I load the page, the `Book.countByApproved(true)` query is logged, so I assume this means that the results are not being retrieved from the query cache? I'm running everything locally, so there's no possibility that the cache is being missed because the cached query result has been invalidated (by the actions of another user).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll look at the [JIRA issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10119) you filed, but it looks like a problem with dynamic finders, since HQL works:

```
Book.executeQuery(
   'select count(*) from Book where name=:name',
   [name: 'foo'], [cache: true])
```

as does a criteria query:

```
def count = Book.createCriteria().count {
   eq 'name', 'foo'
   cache true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've linked to the JIRA so others can follow it's progress